# How to draw a circle in silverlight using coordinates?

Tags: silverlight, graphics, runtime, geometry

I am making an application in Silverlight. In that application I want to draw a circle at runtime using coordinates. I have drawn the circle dynamically but I want to that circle at specific co-ordinates(X,Y). But I am  not getting that.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse() { Width = 150, Height = 150, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                                              HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                                              VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
            };
            ellipse.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
            ellipse.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(ellipse);

            TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello", HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
            textblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            textblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(textblock);
```

And have a look in below sites.....

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/06/28/Silverlight-Bing-Maps-Draw-Circle-Around-Latitude-Longitude-Location.aspx

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/07/how-to-create-circular-loader-using.html

HOpe this post will help you to solve your problem... If so please mark it answer...

Comment: I write the same code as u gave but if i change the value 0 to any other value,still i am getting the circle at the same position. ellipse.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 100);
            ellipse.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 100);

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, use a `canvas` container and set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attributes on the ellipse. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left(v=vs.95).aspx (and the corresponding Canvas.Top article) for more information.